# Tip Calculator statement confusion

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator

Here is the code. Basically after I enter the second customers bill amount it will prematurely read me a tip and asks if there is another customer. I want it to ask me if there is another customer but I don't want it to ask about the tip till I enter "n". Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class H3_TipCalc {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your bill amount.");
    double bill = input.nextDouble();

    String multiplecust = ("Y");
    //int mc=1;

    while (multiplecust.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 

    {


            Scanner usrin = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Is there another customer? y or n?");
        multiplecust = usrin.nextLine();
        //mc++;



        if (multiplecust.equals("y")){
            System.out.println("Please enter their bill amount.");

            }
        else if (multiplecust.equals("n")){
            System.out.println("What tip prcentage would you like to use? Enter as a decimal.");
        }

        double tip = usrin.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your tip owed will be " + bill*tip + ".");
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `else if`, you can either enter the last customer's bill amount or the tip percentage, but not both. Instead, try this logic:

```
while( there are more individual customer amounts to enter ) {
    enter next customer amount
}

get tip percentage

show final bill
```

Notice that the tip percentage is entered after the while loop, because it's just a one-time entry.

Answer (score 0):

You got your logic twisted.

Better move the complete logic inside the loop and check for exit at the end of it (not the start):

```
do
  read bill amount
  read tip amount
  read next customer
while (wants to continue)
```